# Taking the Response from the Printer by using Xon and Xoff

Tags: android

```
how to retrieve the printer response from the Bluetooth printer in android by using X-On and X-Off. I have tried but It is not working. I have tried with the following code but it is not working:

CommPortIdentifier portId  = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM");
SerialPort sPort = (SerialPort)portId .open(this.getClass().getName(), 30000);
sPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                                            sPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_XONXOFF_IN | SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_XONXOFF_OUT);

 OutputStream os = sPort.getOutputStream();
 os=  sPort.getOutputStream();
 InputStream is = sPort.getInputStream(); 
os.write(baos.toByteArray(), 0, baos.toByteArray().length);
 StringBuffer inputBuffer = new StringBuffer();

do{
     for(int newData = is.read();newData != -1; newData = is.read())
      {
        inputBuffer.append((char)newData);
      }

      try
       {
         Thread.sleep(300);
       }
      catch
       {
       }
  }while(inputBuffer.length() <= 0);

String sDataIn = inputBuffer.toString();
```

In the above program when the flow comes in the following line it give an error:
CommPortIdentifier portId  = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM");

Error is::java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Answer (score 0):

Huh? `CommPortIdentifier` class does not exist in Android. How did you even get this to compile?

Also, Android is not Windows so serial ports (if they existed) would not be called "COM".

If you want to talk to your Bluetooth printer, first make sure it supports RFCOMM as this is the only Bluetooth protocol that is available in Android API, second see the Bluetooth tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

Comment: we have API that is jar file "javax.comm" which gives us a class 'CommPortIdentifier'. apart from that let us assume CommPortIdentifier will not work. than which is other possible methode to listen to bluetooth printer because we tired bluetoothSocket.getInputStream() but this is not giving anything on that stream. i just want to add one more point that our requirment is we want to listen xon(decimal value= 17) and xoff(decimal value= 19)(sent while memory buffer overflows) flag sent by the printer while its memory buffer overflows.

Comment: You can not just take a class from desktop java and expect it to work on Android. I'm pretty sure "javax.comm" relies on low level features not present on Android - for on e, serial ports are not available on Android.

Comment: About your bluetooth problem - I don't know, you have not shown any code. Also make sure your printer supports RFCOMM.

Comment: hi peter i am giving you our code the below method will do the our printing job also we have taken the input stream but it is not giving any output

Comment: this what i am reading                                              is = bslocal.getInputStream();
  
     InputStreamReader isr1 = new InputStreamReader(is);
     BufferedReader bfr1 = new BufferedReader(isr1);
     long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
     while (true) {
      if(is.available() > 0)
      {
       String str1 = bfr1.readLine();
             is.close();
       bfr1.close();
       start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      }
           if(System.currentTimeMillis() - start > 2000) {break;}

     }

Comment: bs is bluetooth socket  thanks if you could reply fast on that we are runnuing out of time of this project thanks again